# <pre> tag not styling

Tags: html, css, font-family, pre

I want to style text on my website inside a `<pre>` tag but it will never work.

I have tried putting this in my CSS:

```
pre {
    font-family: Georgia;
}
```

And I have also tried putting it inline like this:

```
<pre style=”font-family: Georgia;”>
```

But none of these work, the font stays as monospace.

These things work [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_pre_default_css), but not on my website.

Why is this happening? If there is no solution, is there an alternative to the `<pre>` tag which lets me have line breaks?

Comment: Could you provide more context? An isolated snippet of how you're loading the stylesheet and using the pre tag would be best.

Comment: Have you tried the following: `pre {font-family: Georgia !important;}` -- this will override any other styles.

Comment: @CharlesAddis Yes, this worked!

Comment: @jez glad I could help, `!important` will override any other styles by default, so use it sparingly.

Comment: @CharlesAddis I just realised I had two stylesheets loaded on the page, so I just removed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two stylesheets on one page which caused the pre text to be monospace. Removing one of them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try important

```
pre {
    font-family: Georgia !important;
}


<pre style=”font-family: Georgia !important;”>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the class selector to style the pre tag with CSS.
HTML code

```
<pre class="code">  Text Here </pre>
```

CSS code

```
.code { font-family: Georgia; background-color: #A8CBFF; }
```

You can check out more uses [on an article I wrote here](http://www.scholarsglobe.com/2016/07/how-to-style-pre-tag-in-html-using-css.html)